# Trying to get vertical tabs to work

Tags: html

I am trying to get vertical tabs to work for my practice website. I am new to html, but have been stumped on this for a few hours, any help appreciated!
This is the problem: When I implement the code from [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/tabs.html#tabs-deeplink-3) website into my project, it shows up wierd and not like the beginning. Here are my files and picture of what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
  <p><font face="verdana"size="5">About Me</font></p>
  <br>
  <p><font face="verdana"size="5">Programming Work</font></p>
  <br>
  <p><font face="verdana"  size="5">About This Website</font></p>
  ul class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
  <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel11">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel21">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel31">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel41">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs-content">
     <div class="content active" id="panel11">
        <p>This is the first panel of the basic tab example. You can place all sorts of content here including a grid.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="content" id="panel21">
        <p>This is the second panel of the basic tab example. This is the second panel of the basic tab example.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="content" id="panel31">
        <p>This is the third panel of the basic tab example. This is the third panel of the basic tab example.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="content" id="panel41">
        <p>This is the fourth panel of the basic tab example. This is the fourth panel of the basic tab example.</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

The website I cited did not have any css or js, so I assumed this would work. Any help would be apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To do this easily, you will need more than just html. My favourite way is using AngularJS for the tabbing and Bootstrap for the UI.

However, jQuery would suffice.

Found an example online for you. I take no credit for the code. http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/nn2qw/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical {
        padding: 0;
        width: 42em;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-widget-header {
        border: none;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
        float: left;
        width: 10em;
        background: #CCC;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        border-right: 1px solid gray;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
        clear: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0.2em 0;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        right: -2px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.6em 1em;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
        margin-bottom: 0.2em;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .ui-tabs.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
        float: left;
        width: 28em;
        border-left: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 0;
        position: relative;
        left: -1px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#a">Tab A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#b">Tab B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#c">Tab C</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#d">Tab D</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="a">
        Content of A
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        Content of B
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        Content of C
    </div>
    <div id="d">
        Content of D
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#tabs')
        .tabs()
        .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```